# Dlookup function in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to look up some values with my dlookup function in Access. I'm going into queries and pulling data with 2 different criteria. So I pull data from a query then I'm inserting it into a temp table. I'm having a hard time avoiding NULL values.

```
 With rs2
    While Not .EOF
        lngVendorID = rs2("CompanyID")
        lngUnitPrice = rs2("UnitPrice")
        'Beginning Count
        lngBegCount = (DLookup("BegCount", "qryBegInv", "UnitPrice = " & [lngUnitPrice] & " AND CompanyID = " & [lngCompanyID] & ""))
        If IsNull(lngBegCount) Or lngBegCount = "" Then
            lngBegCount = 0
        End If
        .Edit
        rs2("BegInvCount") = lngBegCount
        .Update
        rs2.MoveNext
        Wend
```

I keep getting a variety of errors. Basically I want to see if `DLOOKUP` value is null, if it is, then use a 0 and insert that into the `rs2("BegInvCount")`, if it isn't null, then insert the `lngBegCount` into `rs2("BegInvCount")`.

Comment: What are the errors and what are the circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Nz()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function to handle NULL values:

```
lngBegCount = Nz(DLookup("BegCount", "qryBegInv", _
    "UnitPrice = " & lngUnitPrice & " AND CompanyID = " & lngCompanyID & ""), 0)
```

You don't need brackets around variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all i needed!